# Python: how to delete key from one dictionary if it does not exist in another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, compare, key, del

I have two dictionaries with keys as string and values as integer:

```
ground = {"url1":1,"url2":2,....}
prediction = {"url1":5,"url2":3,....}
```

The thing I want to do is to delete key in **ground** if it does not exist in **prediction**.

I wrote the easiest thing that came to my head:

```
for key in ground:        
    if key not in prediction:
        del ground[key]
```

and also tried this:

```
for key in ground:
    if not key in prediction.keys():
        del ground[key]
```

Neither worked. How can I achieve the goal?

Comment: Didn't work *how*? The second, at least, works fine for me.

Comment: @DanielRoseman dictionnary can't change its size during iteration. This raises a RuntimeError (on python 2.7)

Comment: The first one does, yes. But not the second.

Comment: The second can raise the same exception. For the same reason. See responses below.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary:

```
ground = {k: ground[k] for k in ground if k in prediction}
```

Or iterate over the keys of the `ground` dictionary using `ground.keys()` in Python 2, or `list(ground.keys())` in Python 3 (also works in Python 2). This returns a new list which is not affected when keys are removed from the `ground` dictionary:

```
for k in list(ground.keys()):
    if k not in prediction:
        del ground[k]
```

Comment: Dictionnary comprehension should be `ground = {k: ground[k] for k in ground if k not in prediction}`

Comment: @loutre: Almost. My original answer was wrong, but your logic is inverted.

Answer (score 0):

You loop over the dict and delete a key inside the same loop. That's why it may not work. Try:

```
pred_set = set(prediction.keys())
g_set = set(ground.keys())
for key in g_set - pred_set:
    del ground[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt works fine in Python 2. In Python 3, `keys()` is a view rather than a list, so would give the same error as the first: dictionary changed size during iteration. To fix this, convert it to a list first:

```
for key in list(ground.keys()):
  if key not in prediction:
    del ground[key]
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine now